# What happens if the certificate of a signed jar (with timestamp) expires

Tags: java, jar-signing

I signed a jar (of an applet) with timestamp 2 years ago. The cert is about to expire. What will happen? Will there be a warning to the user, will it simply work? Will it stop working?

I didn't add any specific code to the applet to deal with the timestamp. I only included the -tsa url when signing.

Edit: it keeps working.

Comment: this is mostly a case of "try it to find out": create a jar with a cert that has an explicit expiration set to one minute from now, compile, wait a minute, and run your application. Then see what it does.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Prior to Java 5 SE, signed jar's whose signing certificate had expired would no longer be valid or usable.

With Java 5 SE and greater, signed jar's whose signing certificate expires  will continue to work. The expired certificate, however, can not be used to sign any further jar's.

From Oracle's docs: Java SE 8 Documentation > [Signature Timestamp Support](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/time-of-signing.html):

> Prior to J2SE 5.0, the signature generated by `jarsigner` contained no information about when the signature was generated. With no other information available, systems/deployers (including users of the Java Plug-in) often based their validity assessment of a signed JAR file on the validity of the signing certificate. When the signing certificate expires, systems/deployers conclude that the signature, and hence, the JAR file, has expired. Because signing certificates typically expire annually, this caused customers significant problems by forcing them to re-sign deployed JAR files annually.
>
> Starting in J2SE 5.0, `jarsigner` can generate signatures that include a timestamp, thus enabling systems/deployer (including Java Plug-in) to check whether the JAR file was signed while the signing certificate was still valid. In addition, APIs were added in J2SE 5.0 to allow applications to obtain the timestamp information.

Answer (score 1):

It will work while the timestamp certificate remains valid. No warning (except for regular security warnings when starting an applet) will be displayed to the user.

Once the timestamp certificate expires or is revoked, your signed jar will become untrusted.